# SSH without password

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm unable to ssh without a password for some reason on a new CentOS box.

I've tried following these guides:

- http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/

But neither are working.  I even checked my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.  `PubkeyAuthentication yes` was originally commented out so I uncommented that line and restarted sshd but still to no avail.  Any thoughts of anything else that could be missing?

I'm trying to ssh from server A to server B as root.  Thus, logged in as root on one box, then ssh to the next as root without being prompted for a password.

UPDATE

I ran a `ssh -v ...` but cannot copy/paste into here.  Everything looked good until this line:

```
debug1: Next authentication method:  gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor Code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195
```

Comment: ssh from where to where using what key?

Comment: What is the output of `ssh -v ...` when you try to connect?

Comment: See my edit above....

Comment: Over at the Ubuntu forums there was a [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=794765) that suggested it was because of a [OpenSSH vulnerability](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=793517) - and the fix appears to be regenerating your server keys.

Comment: Also make sure your `.ssh` subdirectory has permissions of 700.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small how-to for public key based authentication for CentOS/Red Hat/etc...

**On the SSH client:**

```
ssh-keygen # Accept all defaults, do not enter a password.
ssh-copy-id USER@SERVER_IP
restorecon -R ~/.ssh
```

**On the SSH server:**

```
# Login to the server normally (with password)
restorecon -R ~/.ssh
```

**Public key based authentication should now work.**

Comment: Accepting this one as the answer, though it wasn't what was needed to solve the issue.  Point at SERVER_IP is what lead me to the issue at hand.  My /etc/hosts file had the fully qualified name of the server despite the hostname of the machine not actually containing the domainname.  Additionally the domain name was not set on the machine but rather the domain name is used for DNS.  Modifying the entry in /etc/hosts corrected the issue.  Thanks all to helped and let this hopefully help folks in the future.

Answer (score 2):

These problems (which *are* usually permissions related) are much more easily debugged from the server side.  I recommend that you start another sshd in debug mode with: `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222` which will start another sshd on port 2222, then run `ssh -p 2222 user@sshserver` on the client side.  Watch what comes out of the sshd when your client tries to authenticate.

Permissions problems don't have to be just `/home/$USER/.ssh`.  it could also be a problem with `/`, `/home`, or `/home/$USER`.  If any of those are group writable it can be a problem.

Another common problem is that you mis-paste and put linebreaks in the middle of your key in the authorized_keys file

Answer (score 1):

```
serverA# ls -lah /root
serverA# ls -lah /root/.ssh
serverA# selinuxenabled 
serverA# echo $?

serverB# ls -lah /root
serverB# ls -lah /root/.ssh
serverB# senlinuxenabled
serverB# echo $?
```

If that doesn't show you the problem, try the following.  ServerA is the client and serverB the ssh server.

On serverB, edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config.  Find the line that looks like:

> ## LogLevel INFO

Change it to:

> LogLevel VERBOSE

Then:

```
serverB# /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

On serverA:

```
serverA# ssh -vvv root@serverb
```

You can now reivew the /var/log/secure file on serverB for clues.

As a final tip, please review:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-keyc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Check your permissions, they should be

drwx------

for your **.ssh** *directory* and

-rw-------

for your **authorized_keys** *file*.

So, to set the permissions properly, try this:

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SELinux enabled, then this is a common problem...

**Run the following on the SSH server:**

```
restorecon -R /home/$USER/.ssh
```

**or, for root:**

```
restorecon -R /root/.ssh
```

'Nuff Said...

Comment: That did not work.  I'm still being prompted for a password.

Comment: Where did you run the command?  Server or client?  Hint:  Run it on both.

Comment: I ran it on both.

Comment: See my other answer...